# Reset application settings to a clear/clean state

Tags: qt, qml, registry, settings

I use QML [Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) in my application. Therefore, while developing and testing, every time I open the app, it remembers the settings.

How can I clear the settings status so that I can simulate the very first launch of the app by a user? Thanks.

Comment: One option is to delete the settings file.

Comment: @JarMan Where is it? Where in Windows registry?

Comment: The default location is platform specific. But you can specify your own path with the `filename` property.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks, it helped me to simulate the very first launch, by using `fileName` and deleting the file ...

Comment: Well, great. Then I'll write it as an answer in case it helps others.

Comment: @JarMan Please do so! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the file that is used to store the Settings by setting the `filename` property.

```
Settings {
    filename: "/path/to/my/settings/file"
}
```

Then when you want to clear the Settings, simply delete the file. Everything should start over with default values after that.